# In Node.js, finding the original client URL when app is behind a reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, reverse-proxy

I'm working on a Node.js/Express application that, when deployed, sits behind a reverse proxy.

For example: `http://myserver:3000/` is where the application actually sits, but users access it at `https://proxy.mycompany.com/myapp`.

I can get the original user agent request's host from a header passed through easily enough (if the reverse proxy is configured properly), but how do I get that extra bit of path and protocol information from the original URL accessed by the browser?

When my application has to generate redirects, it needs to know that the end user's browser expects the request to go to not only to `proxy.mycompany.com` over `https`, but also under a sub-path of `myapp`.

So far all I can get access to is `proxy.mycompany.com`, which isn't enough to create a valid redirect.

For dev purposes I'm using a reverse proxy setup in nginx, but my company is using Microsoft's ISA as well as HAProxy.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with this, can you share the code you are currently using to get the domain, and note any of the alternatives you've tried thus far with their results?

Comment: If you haven't had any trouble, how do you deal with a redirect of `/` issued by your apps not taking your user to the root of the proxy server instead of to the root of your app? Remember, the rev-proxy is inserting a folder path into the mix: https://proxyhost/myapp/ --> http://serverhost:3000/

Comment: I use a base tag. but, then the question becomes, what do you put in the base tag? I used `./`, but that was on an app that's actually at the root. My other app that isn't at the root doesn't do any redirection so it doesn't have that problem i guess.

Comment: Exactly. That's the issue - what is the base? Right now I have to hard-code it based on the environment and such.  Knowing what it is programmatically is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would expect ./ to work, assuming a SPA.

Comment: Not a SPA. It's an OAuth2 server.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is done with `x-forwarded-*` headers which are inserted by the reverse proxy itself. For example:

```
x-forwarded-host: foo.com
x-forwarded-proto: https
```

Take a look here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html

Probably you can configure nginx to insert whatever `x-` header you want, but the convention (standard?) seems to be the above.

If you're reverse proxying into a sub-path such as `/myapp`, that definitely complicates matters. Presumably that sub-path should be a configuration option available to both nginx and your app.

Comment: Except that the host and the protocol are not enough. I need the folder structure as well.  What you have won't tell me that the reverse proxy is sitting my app behind an extra folder named `myapp`.

Comment: That's what I meant by it complicating things, and needing a config option.

Comment: Yeah, missed that last sentence in your post.